# Display a file located in a website with SWIFT

Tags: ios, swift, file

Can someone point me in the right direction about opening/reading/display a file (txt) that is located in a website?

I've tried some things but nothing has worked except to display the exact url as a string not the contents of the url.

Comment: Could you post your current method code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use UIWebView.

1. Go to your storyboard, drag UIWebView to your view. Make an outlet connection to your view controller (if you don't know how to do it let me know in the comment).
2. In your view controller do this:

.

```
let url = NSURL(string: "https://wordpress.org/plugins/about/readme.txt")
webView.loadRequest(NSURLRequest(URL: url!))
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

If you want to use HTTP you have to tell Xcode to allow http (this is since iOS9). See image below...
Otherwise you would get the error:

App Transport Security has blocked a cleartext HTTP (http://) resource load since it is insecure. Temporary exceptions can be configured via your app's Info.plist file.

[image]

Comment: I am lost.  Could you be more explicit in the code?  I added a let in front of this to make it correct.  But this only assigns a value, what command do I code to actually populate the web view?

Comment: Sorry for the forgot "let" in first line and "!" in second line. I've updated my answer with the corrected code. It should work now.

Comment: Thank you.  I have error free code and your text file shows.  But when I put my URL in there it does not show.  I have got this far before but now can't seem to figure out why my text file does not show.

Comment: Can you paste your link here?

Comment: http://saveyourdata.biz/images/text.txt

Comment: I appreciate the help you are giving me.  This is pretty frustrating since I know I have the code right.  I even created a new project that just display a web view and it is not working there either.  Something must be wrong on my setup/environment.

Comment: I see what's wrong. It's because since iOS9 you have to explicitly tell that you're going to use http instead of https. Let me check, I'll tell you in few minutes what to do.

Comment: I've updated my answer to fix http issue. I've added "App Transport Security Setting" and set "YES" for "Allow Arbitrary Loads".

Comment: Andre, thanks for helping that did the trick.  I was able to find the dictionary and add it.  For some who started on Assembly, Fortran and Cobol and then onto object-c , C C+ and so on this is somewhat different.  Thanks for helping me!!